# Final Cut Pro and/or Compressor exports not showing progress

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, final-cut-pro, apple

Pretty much any time I am exporting from Final Cut Pro, either via it's native "share" interface or by "send to compressor" the progress bar does absolutely nothing for a very long time, although in Compressor I can see at least the "elapsed time" is moving.

When I open Activity Monitor though I can see my CPU is working hard, and there is a process using a ton of resources called "VTEncoderXPCService".

Am I doing something wrong? Is this normal behavior?

With short videos it may only linger in this state for a few minutes, but right now I am compressing nine hours of footage and it has so far been in this state of not showing any progress for ~25 minutes.